# Test whether a sample is at least a certain number of standard deviations away from a value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test

Let's start of with an unknown normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Often in hypothesis testing, the null hypothesis is something like: "The mean of the probability distribution from which the sample is drawn is smaller than a given value", or

$H_{0,1}: μ < μ_0$

This can be tested in with a one sample, one tail t test. What I want to test is a little bit different. My null hypothesis is as follows:

$H_{0,2}: μ - 2\sigma < μ_0$

I want to know if the mean of my distribution is at least two standard deviation above a given value. The true standard deviation is of course also unknown, and must therefore be approximated from the sample.

The solution I came up with was to calculate the sample standard deviation and then perform a t test:

$H_{0,3}: μ < μ_1 \text{, with }\mu_1 = \mu_0 + 2s$

Here, $s$ is the sample standard deviation. I am not sure if this approach is statistically valid. Would a p value calculated using this method be meaningful? Are there better methods I can use?

Please let me know if anything is unclear. I look forward to your answers.Thanks in advance.